# float number corrupted in selected device

Tags: android

Recently, I encountered float number corrupted problem in selected Android device. I was wondering, anyone of you had encountered the similar problem as mine, ***yet have a way to reproduce it with a simplified code block?***

I encountered similar problem in Nexus 5 devices. The problem doesn't happen in Genymotion Emulator.

It only happen in selected for loop code block, and it is extremely difficult to re-produce in other code block.

My situation is as follow :-

```
float rectangleWidth2 = 0.0f;
float startX = (float) (left + xPixelsPerUnit * (xValue - minX));
float stopX = startX;
float _left = startX - rectangleWidth2;
float _right = stopX + rectangleWidth2;

// I expect "_left" and "_right" will have same value. However, at this point,
// "_right" will become an arbitary large value, something like 5.3482353354E20
// However, I expect the value range for "_left" and "_right" within [-1000,1000]
```

If I change the code to

```
float _left = startX - rectangleWidth2;
float _right = startX + rectangleWidth2;

// "_left" and "_right" will then having same value.
```

A "realiable" workaround for my case, is to avoid using float as suggested by reporter. I use double whenever possible, and only perform necessary float casting, when there is a need.

Same problem occur, regardless I'm using Eclipse or Android Studio. I'm going to get Nexus 4 this week, to see whether same problem occur still...

### Referenced Links

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58698
- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/660746-problem-with-random-float-value-on-android/

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to reproduce it unless you include more code. Here I replaced the unknown variables with ints and both have the same value. Perhaps you could explain your test case better?

Comment: @DavidCesarino I want to extract the problematic code block, and make it as standalone code. However, after I do so, myself no longer able to reproduce the problem. This kind of bug is scary with my current "seems to workaround" is replace float with double. I will wait till my Nexus 4 to see whether it has same problem. My highly suspicion is that, certain hardware vendors don't implement floating point hardware (or virtual machine?) correctly.

Comment: Maybe try to debug your code and output all values before & after calculation first? I'm using Nexus 4, so I am kind of interested to research about this, but seeing that Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 are both from LG, I doubt the issue will be gone though.

Comment: @AndrewT. I will try to test with Nexus S (real) and Nexus 4 (real), and update this thread regarding my test result. At the same time, I will find a way on how to make a minimal workable project, to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I'm interested in this. :-) Not sure what kind of devices you have access to, but I have the GN, N4, N5 and N7 (both) and the N10, if that helps. I don't know, just offering help in case you need.

Comment: @DavidCesarino Since I'm currently rushing for next version app release, I will temporary put the experiment on side first, by using "double replaced float" as workaround. I will come back to this thread after that, with a simplified app version, hopefully can reproduce the bug. Thanks for interested.